# Ruby if regex help needed

Tags: ruby, regex, if-statement, syntax

I am attempting to modify someone's script.

I have managed to modify everything but there is one problem left I am unable to solve:

```
 disp_status("\tAnswer: #{convert_err(results["status"])}")
```

This produces various outputs as it is run, however, when the output is "ERROR", I want it to do an action. I am not sure how to limit it to "Error", as it appears to always run the method no matter the output.

What I tried was:

```
if #{convert_err(results["status"])} =~ /ERROR/
```

and a lot of similar iterations without any luck. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In ruby interpolation doesn't work without double-quotes. But using interpolation here is an over kill, so just change the line in question from:

```
if #{convert_err(results["status"])} =~ /ERROR/
```

To

```
if convert_err(results["status"]) =~ /ERROR/
```

And should it should work! :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think the `.include?` method might be helpful. You could do:

```
if "#{convert_err(results["status"])}".include?("ERROR")
```

Furthermore if convert_err returns a string you could just call:

```
if convert_err(results["status"]).include?("ERROR")
```

And another option would be to call `.to_s` which will convert the result of convert_err to a string. So that would look like:

```
if convert_err(results["status"]).to_s.include?("ERROR")
```

For further reference read: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.4/String.html#method-i-include-3F

Comment: I keep getting:

 NoMethodError undefined method `include'